# Wordpress pagenavi archive page issue

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Trying to create a tag archive page for a custom post type, the following works and all posts are displayed, but the wp_pagenavi function is not working at the end:

```
<?php

$args = array(
     'post_type'      => array( 'blog' ),
     'tag' => get_queried_object()->slug,
     'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
     'post_status'    => 'publish',
     'orderby'        => 'title',
     'order'          => 'ASC'
);

$tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $tag_query->have_posts()) :
  while( $tag_query->have_posts()) :
      $tag_query->the_post();
?>
        
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>

<p class="meta"><?php the_date(); ?> / Written by <?php the_author(); ?></p>

<?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>
<div class="tags" style="padding-top: 10px; ">
<p class="tags"><?php echo get_the_tag_list('Tags: ', ' | ', ''); ?></p>
</div>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>    

<?php endif; ?>
    
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                
<div id="pagenavi"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>
```